# Circular nature of logic.

Tags: logic

Consider the following syllogism:

premises:

$1.$ $A$ is a man.

$2.$ Every man has a heart.

Conclusion:

$3.$ $A$ has a heart.

Logic says that $1$ and $2$ allows us to come to the conclusion that $3$ is true. But, first of all how did we know $A$ is a man? If $A$ doesn't have a heart, we don't call him a man in the first place right?

I know that in propositional logic we don't question the premises. We just take them as they are without questioning the basis of such sentences. I think it is an inherent problem of logic. May be, in the development of logic, mathematicians may have encountered that problem and questioned such bases that logic is built.

## My Question:

Although this is considered as a valid reasoning in current logic, I claim that this is yet another [circular reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning) in disguise. Disprove that (using current logic or any other paradigm for that matter).

Comment: You told your Readers (myself included) that A is a man.  I only know this because you told me.  It makes little sense to tell me that, then ask "how we knew A is a man."

Comment: Considering the *massive* number of *major* spelling errors and grammatical mistakes, I assume that English is not your native language.  It may help you more to ask the question in your native language, whatever that may be, so that explanations can be given in a way you are more likely to understand.  I expect that the root of problem is merely an issue caused by a language barrier.

Comment: You are welcome to post suitable Questions on Math.SE, but anyone will be free to post answers.  Be sure to review the [Tour of Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of what excellent Questions will look like.

Comment: As for the question "*If $A$ doesn't have a heart, we don't call him a man in the first place, right?*"  You are correct.  Given the assumptions "*$A$ does not have a heart*" and "*Every man has a heart*" we can indeed conclude $A$ is not a man.  You might try reading [this wikipedia page on contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), or waiting for your friend to translate it for you.

Comment: so it is not there a cyclic nature in logic? @JMoravitz?

Comment: @JMoravitz `It may help you more to ask the question in your native language` That's risky advice around MSE, judging by the quick close votes to that edit.

Comment: Why this is put on hold. As @hardmath suggested as the tour to this website says we can ask problems about `history of mathematics`, `understanding mathematical concepts and theorems`.

Comment: @dxiv You might not have seen some of the earlier comments made by the OP, but I am not convinced that the OP can understand more than half of the words of any given sentence being said here, much less the nuances in language necessary to adequately convey mathematical concepts in logic rigorously.  There were a good half-dozen comments from the OP, each of which with only half of the words spelled correctly (*poplem instead of problem, queschen instead of question*) where the OP claimed that noone else who speaks their native language studies math in the whole world.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry for my bad English. "I" edited the post ;-). Please feel free to answer or comment on the problem. :-). And for those guys who put this question on hold, please tell me where exactly I am unclear on the problem so that I can correct it.

Comment: @JMoravitz I missed those, indeed. However, coincidentally or not, the question was summarily closed right after the OP changed the language (before reversing it again). Maybe a dual-language post (with one being maybe an automated translation) would have better chances at being well-received on MSE. That said, I find the question reasonably comprehensible as of the latest edit, and voted to reopen it.

Comment: @ aquire, what is unclear is how much you do or don't understand about the concept of a [premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premise).  By accepting "$A$ is a man" as a premise, it then follows that "$A$ is a man" is true.  This is circular, yes, but it is not a bad thing in this example.  You may also want to read about [axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom).  "*Why can we assume $A$ is a man/Why can we assume things?*"  Because we can.  Without premises/axioms there can be no conclusions.

Comment: @JMoravitz I haven't said in the post that  `by accepting "A is a man" as a premise, it then follows that "A is a man" is true`.  I propose in the post that  "$A$ is a man"  $\wedge$ "Everyman has a heart" $\Rightarrow$ "$A$ has a heart" is circular reasoning in disguise.

Comment: My understanding about premises: `I know that in propositional logic  we don't question the premises`.

Comment: " But, first of all how did we know A is a man?"  Because you told us so.   You said "A is a man".

Comment: "*I propose in the post that... $\implies A$ has a heart' is circular reasoning in disguise.*"  Why?  "$A$ has a heart" is not one of the original premises.  Circular reasoning occurs when you have a premise which implies itself and thinking that this in turn implies that the premise must always be true even in cases where it is not explicitly included as a premise.  That is not the case for the implication you refer to.  "$A$ has a heart" is a conclusion which was not included as a premise but which is implied by the premises "$A$ is a man" and "Every man has a heart."

Comment: @JMoravitz because the premise "$A$ has heart" is intertwined with the conclusion although we try to blindly make them separate and say, "...ah ha! A has a heart... ! I didn't know that... at the begining before I come to the conclusion."

Comment: @fleablood How did I construct the premise "$A$" is a man. When I was constructing the premise haven't I looked into the fact whether "$A$  has a heart"? Do you see my point?

Comment: "*When I was constructing the premise haven't I looked into the fact whether 'A has a heart'*?"  No... you didn't.  Perhaps you are thinking that all of the statements (1),(2), and (3), are being taken as premises.  They aren't.  They were merely listed together at the start for convenience and at the time of listing they were not yet even stated as being premises.  In the implication $((1)\wedge (2))\implies (3)$ only the first two are premises and not the third, just like how in the (*false*) implication $(1)\implies(2)$ only (1) is a premise and (2) is not a premise.

Comment: "How did I construct the premise "A" is a man"  By opening your mouth and saying "A is a man".   "Do you see my point?"  Not in the least.

Comment: @JMoravitz Perhaps you are thinking that all of the statements (1),(2), and (3), are being taken as premises. No. I specifically took (1) and (2) as premises here. I'll edit the post if that's confusing.

Comment: When you are told A is a man, you know he is a man and every thing that pertains to being a man will apply to A.  It doesn't not matter if you the reader knows what those things are or whether you the reader actually thought them through.  When we ask "A is a man; what can you conclude" we are not asking you to *invent* or create anything.  We are saying "there are many things about A that you may or may know; which can you conclude with certainty" and one is "he has a heart".

Comment: @fleablood I see your point. Give me some time to ponder on that. I suddenly feel that my question is so foolish... :-) I'm no good in mathematics arena I guess..

Comment: the implication is that somehow through an act of the universe, A was created and he is a man and he has a heart and hair and toenails and somehow the universe decreed that being a man means you have a heart. And somehow the universe slapped you awake and said "Hey, acquire!  Every man has a heart.  So says the universe" and then the universe tosses A at you and say "Hey! acquire!  The is A-- he is a man" and now you are left shaken awake with only a brain, memory, and logic.  You conclude, "well, he's a man and all men have hearts so he must have a heart...."

Comment: Ha ha what I lack in mathematics is drama. If theorems and definitions in math were so dramatic I would never miss a point. Thanks everyone for your clarifications. Can you compile an answer for this question @fleablood. Am I asking you too much? If so I'll answer it myself... Ah I suddenly realized this is on hold. Anyway my special thanks goes to flea, JM, hard  and dxiv who came to my rescue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80786/discussion-between-aquire-and-fleablood).

Answer (score 2):

> But, first of all how did we know $A$ is a man?

For example because someone told us that $A$ is a man.

> If $A$ doesn't have a heart, we don't call him a man in the first place right?

Well, assuming the second claim, “Every man has a heart”, is true, then from $A$ not having a heart we can *conclude* that $A$ is not a man. And yes, that second claim might well come directly from a definition.

> I know that in propositional logic we don't question the premises. We just take them as they are without questioning the basis of such sentences. I think it is an inherent problem of logic.

Quite the opposite, it's actually the strength of logic. It means that we don't need to know anything about men or hearts to know that anyone who claims at the same time that $A$ is a man, that all men have hearts, and that $A$ has no heart, must be wrong.

> Although this is considered as a valid reasoning in current logic, I claim that this is yet another circular reasoning in disguise. Disprove that (using current logic or any other paradigm for that matter).

It is not a circular reasoning because there's no circle in it. It would only be circular reasoning if before we had used $A$ having a heart in order to determine that $A$ is a man. But we didn't; that fact was just given.

Note that also in real life we usually don't check whether someone has a heart when we determine whether he is a man. Rather we look at their outside, and draw our conclusions from that. The heart is not seen from the outside.

Comment: `Note that also in real life ... not seen from the outside.`  It's a bit confusing now. So are you telling that $A$ might not have a heart at all? So current logic may claim wrong conclusions. Is that what you meant? Is it not a discrepancy of current logic? Either the reasoning is circular or current logic can claim unreasonable conclusions. That's what I am getting right now. :-(

Comment: @aquire: No, all I'm saying is that you usually don't check whether someone has a heart before you decide he's a man. At least I assume you're not running around with a stethoscope to check whether people around you have hearts, are you?

Comment: `...you usually don't check whether someone has a heart before you decide he's a man.` If the determination process doesn't involve checking the heart, isn't there a probability that the person not having a heart? Consider an ideal humanoid $\color{red}A$. Just by looking outside appearance one comes to the conclusion that $\color{red}A$ is a man. Then our premise is wrong. So our conclusion is wrong. That means this is just circular reasoning. i.e. if $\color{red}A$ don't have a heat then $\color{red}A$ don't have a heart. Am I wrong? I'm really really confused. ;-(

Comment: “If the determination process doesn't involve checking the heart, isn't there a probability that the person not having a heart?” — That doesn't follow. For example, say I have irrefutable proof that only men have beards. Then as soon as I determine that someone has a beard, I can conclude that he is a man. And if I in addition know without doubt that all men have hearts, I can conclude that he has a heart. Not that I never explicitly checked that he has a heart; I only checked he has a beard.

Comment: But of course, if the assumptions are wrong, then the conclusions don't follow. But that's not a failure of logic, that's making wrong assumptions. There's still nothing circular, as there's still no circle. Note however that, contrary to your claim, from the falsity of the assumptions it does *not* follow that the conclusion is wrong. For example, for a woman we may incorrectly think she's a man. And then from that incorrect assumption conclude that she has a heart. Does this imply that she has no heart? Obviously not.

Comment: How about the statement every man has a heart? To say that every man has a heart don't we need to check $A$'s heart too. Or is it just induction (i.e. $M_1$ has a heart, $M_2$ has a heart, $\ldots\Rightarrow$ Every man has a heart)? Or else is there a proof that comes to the conclusion that every man has a heart without checking $A$'s heart?

Comment: BTW: `...say I have irrefutable proof that only men ..` I guess you're right. ` But that's not a failure of logic, that's making wrong assumptions.` I didn't said that's a failure.

Answer (score 1):

In logic there are certain **given** facts, which are facts that are assumed true, and then there are **claims**, which we are trying to prove. In saying that $1)$ and $2)$ lead to $3)$, you are using $1)$ and $2)$ as the **given** statements, so it is assumed that $A$ is a man, and therefore has a heart.